# Java integer maths to loop from 0-4 continuously

Tags: java, math, loops, code-formatting

Is there a nicer way to do the count I'm doing below?

I'm sure this must be possible with modulus or something. I'm looking for someway to manipulate `i` instead of using the extra variable `x`. (to beautify this).

Here is the long way round:

```
int MAX = 4;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   System.out.print(x); 
   if(x++; == MAX)
      x = 0;
}
```

Expected outcome:
// 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 .. etc

Comment: Modulus (`%`) is exactly what you need.  Try it!

Comment: Did you *try* using the mod operator "%"?

Comment: Last time I used mod it was just to work out odd or even, more reading needed!

Comment: I think you mean loop 0-3 continuously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {   System.out.print(i % MAX); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just do `x = i % MAX;`

Comment: I meant *substitute* `i % MAX` for `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty clear as is.   While modulus % might save you a few keystrokes, it's not necessary.  Natural human expression is generally preferred, especially if your coding at 4am or coming back to your code 6 months later.